# Paragraph to an array in specified format

Tags: php, arrays, domdocument

I am having Html pragraph like this.

```
<p>This is the sample image</p><img src="test.png"/><p>this is thesample test</p>
```

I want to convet this into following type of array

```
a[0] = This is the sample image;
a[1] = test.png
a[2] = >this is thesample test
```

How it is possible to do  this with php. Can any one give me the suggestions. Here is that sample html content only not a exact content. this content may vary and have different html tags. If the img came, src should be stored in array and contents in correct order.

Comment: is that a typo? the first `<p>` has no closing

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `DOMDocument` yes you could. Get the `nodeValue` or the `attributes` for void tags. Example:

```
$html_string = '<p>This is the sample image</p><img src="test.png"/><p>this is thesample test</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
$a = array();
foreach($elements as $element) {
    if(in_array($element->tagName, array('html', 'body'))) continue;
    if(!empty($element->nodeValue)) {
        $a[] = $element->nodeValue;
    } else {
        foreach($element->attributes as $att) {
            $a[] = $att->value;
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);
```

Should yield this (based on example markup):

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is the sample image
    [1] => test.png
    [2] => this is thesample test
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use preg_match to match a particular tag.

```
$source = "<p> text line </p>";

preg_match("'<p>(.*?)</p>'si", $source, $match);

var_dump($match);
```

you will get the text.

and for all -

```
preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U", $source, $match, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

[php manual for preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)